# What is the correct way to store album artwork?

Tags: storage, id3, albumart

I've been working on an album art fetcher and have been struggling to find a good answer to this question.

Currently, I've been embedding the art into the ID3 tags, because it seems to be the most commonly supported. However, using "cover.jpeg" or "folder.jpeg" has the potential to save a lot of unnecessary space usage, though I'm not entirely sure which media players/file browsers support this automatically.

If using embedded artwork when there is a cover picture in the directory, will all media players choose embedded over it or does it depend? Any resources on the norms for this would also be much appreciated.

What is the best way to store the artwork?

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on the music player. In most cases, my finger in the air says music players tend to prefer embedded art, but there's nothing like any kind of agreed rule.

[In my view, embedded art is the most flexible way forward.](http://www.blisshq.com/music-library-management-blog/2010/08/12/three-advantages-embedding-album-art/)